# Odoo 9 how to append custom view template into existing views?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-view

I'd like to append a template in between KanbanView.buttons and KanbanView.Group to show description field in "project.project" model when I view "project.task" kanban view.

I guess there should be somewhere to append those templates into kanban view but unfortunately, I cannot find it.

What I did is

I created a custom template
layouts.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <templates>
            <t t-name="eric-kanban-view">
                <div>This is Eric's kanban view</div>
            </t>
        </templates>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

and I'd like to add the template to "project.view_task_kanban" to locate above kanban view
project.xml

```xml
<record id="project_task_custom_kanban" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_task_kanban"/>
    <field name="model">project.task</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//templates" position="before">
            <t t-call="eric-kanban-view"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

**openerp**.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Part of Odoo. See LICENSE file for full copyright and licensing details.

{
    'name' : 'project_customized',
    'version' : '1.1',
    'author' : "Eric Lee",
    'description': 'eric\'s Project customized module',
    'installable' : True,
    'data' : [
        'project.xml',
    ],
    'depends' : [
        'project',
    ],
    'qweb': [
        'static/src/xml/layouts.xml',
        'static/src/xml/project.xml',
    ],
}
```

But nothing happened.

Below is the layout I want
[image]

Comment: Jima - specify what outcome you want to see. I have one Odoo9 project with highly personalised "Project" module.
Tadeusz - could you send me your contact details? You are very skilled and I could have some work for you from time to time

Comment: @TadeuszKarpinski What I want to do is I'd like to add a template or a view to show one field from 'project.project' model when in 'project.task' kanban or list view.

Comment: @PiotrCierkosz I'd like to show a field like description from 'project.project' in this kanban view once not repeating

Comment: @Jinna, Could you check my answer, looking forward to your feedback.

Comment: @KbiR The answer you gave me was fine but my client doesn't want to see the title of the project on every task. so your answer was considerable before I found a solution. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a widget by extending kanbanView.

Here is the example:
[image]

Here is the sample code.

**static/src/xml/template.xml**

```xml
<template id="template" xml:space="preserve">

 <t t-name="kanban.sample_header">
   <div class="sample_header" style="width:100%;height:50px;background-color:#fff;">
     <h2>Sample header</h2>
  </div>
</t>
</template>
```

**static/src/js/sample.js**

```js
odoo.define('kanban.sample_dashboard', function (require) {
"use strict";


var core = require('web.core');
var formats = require('web.formats');
var Model = require('web.Model');
var session = require('web.session');
var KanbanView = require('web_kanban.KanbanView');

var QWeb = core.qweb;

var _t = core._t;
var _lt = core._lt;

var sampleHeader = KanbanView.extend({
  display_name: _lt('Dashboard'),
  icon: 'fa-dashboard',
  fetch_data: function() {
      // Overwrite this function with useful data
      return $.when();
  },
  render: function() {
      var super_render = this._super;
      var self = this;

      return this.fetch_data().then(function(result){
          self.show_demo = result && result.nb_opportunities === 0;

          var sales_dashboard = QWeb.render('kanban.sample_header', {
              widget: self,
              show_demo: self.show_demo,
              values: result,
          });
          super_render.call(self);
          $(sales_dashboard).prependTo(self.$el);
      });
  },

});
core.view_registry.add('sample_header', sampleHeader);

return sampleHeader;

})
```

**view.xml**

```xml
<odoo>
 <data>


<template id="assets_backend" name="sample_header" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/kanban/static/src/js/sample_js.js"></script>
    </xpath>
</template>


<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_task_kanban_inherit">
    <field name="name">project.task.kanban.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">project.task</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_task_kanban"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

      <xpath expr="//kanban" position="attributes">
        <attribute name='js_class'>sample_header</attribute>

      </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
 </data>
 </odoo>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: all the resources are loaded but the sample_header doesn't print. And I put console.log() in render function but it doesn't print log

Comment: When I change the code from 'sample_header' to 'kanban' in core.view_registry.add('sample_header', sampleHeader), It shows but not on header but on left hand side like a new stage.

Answer (score 2):

```
<record id="project_task_custom_kanban" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_task_kanban"/>
    <field name="model">project.task</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='name']" position="after">
            <field name="project_id.name"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

So this example should work well. After the task name the name of project will be shown.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know that adding a field to each task is possible. but what i want to do is to show only a project name once not on every task on the page when I click a project to see its tasks

Comment: I just want to show a 'project_id.name' from 'project.project' below create button and above kanban or list view. I just uploaded a picture for your understanding